# Choosing optimal intervals

Tags: linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I have two list of numbers of size N. For example, say `N=6, x=[1, 3, 5, 10, 15, 20]` and `y=[1.5, 3.5, 4.7, 9, 12, 18]`. I would like to divide these two lists into n bins (say n=3 here) in a way that numbers with same index in `x` and `y` end up in the same bins.

For examples, if I use 4 and 11 as the dividing points, I will get `x=[[1,3], [5, 10], [15, 20]]` and `y=[[1.5, 3.5], [4.7, 9], [12, 18]]` which satisfy my requirement.

In some cases, that may not be possible, so I would like to minimize the number of misses.

Is there a way to formulate this using some sort of optimization problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that all $x$ and $y$ values are in the range $[m, M]$. Let $z_1,\dots,z_{n-1}\in [m,M]$ be real variables providing the dividing values for the bins, and for notational convenience let $z_0=m-1$ and $z_N=M$. Introduce binary variables $u_{ij}$, $v_{ij}$ and $w_i$ for $i=1,\dots, N$ and $j=1,\dots,n$. $u$ and $v$ will signal which interval each $x$ and $y$ value (respectively) falls into, and $w_i$ will be 1 whenever $x_i$ and $y_i$ land in different bins. The objective is to minimize $\sum_i w_i$.

We'll need a small positive constant $\epsilon$ to enforce strict inequalities. (In case an $x$ or $y$ value falls on one of the dividing points, we'll arbitrarily assign it to the lower interval.) The constraints are as follows:
\begin{align*}
\sum_j u_{ij} & = 1 \quad \forall i\\
\sum_j v_{ij} & = 1 \quad \forall i\\
\sum_i u_{ij} & \ge 1 \quad \forall j\\
\sum_i v_{ij} & \ge 1 \quad \forall j\\
x_{i} & \le z_{j}+(M-m)(1-u_{ij}) \quad \forall i,j\\
x_{i} & \ge z_{j-1}+\epsilon-(M-m)(1-u_{ij}) \quad \forall i,j\\
y_{i} & \le z_{j}+(M-m)(1-v_{ij}) \quad \forall i,j\\
y_{i} & \ge z_{j-1}+\epsilon-(M-m)(1-v_{ij}) \quad \forall i,j\\
w_{i} & \ge u_{ij}-v_{ij} \quad \forall i,j\\
w_{i} & \ge v_{ij}-u_{ij} \quad \forall i,j.
\end{align*}
Constraints 1 and 2 force each $x$ and $y$ to be assigned to exactly one bin. Constraints 3 and 4 force each bin to contain at least one $x$ and one $y$. Constraints 5 and 6 set $u_{ij}=1$ if and only if $z_{j-1} < x_i \le z_j$, and constraints 7 and 8 do the same for $v$ and $y$. Constraints 9 and 10 force a mismatch penalty if $x$ and $y$ in the same position land in different bins.

Comment: Wow, such a beautiful formulations. Thanks a lot. I actually implemented this in python. And it works. But if N is too large, say N > 100, my MIP solver is not able to solve it anymore.

Comment: It's possible that a different MIP solver might be able to solve it, particularly if you are using an open-source solver and can switch to one of the industry leaders (CPLEX, Gurobi, Xpress, ...). Another to consider is whether different solver parameter settings might help. Then there is the question of what "solve" means -- get a "good" solution in reasonable time, reach proven optimality (zero gap), or something in between.